# jQuery (Mobile): get all checked items (checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked, prop

I got trouble finding a solution to this one.
I have an amount of checkboxes, and I want to get how many of them are checked. 
Each time a box get checked/unchecked, the value needs to update.

What I have so far:

### http://jsfiddle.net/drhmorw5/3/

---

My code so far:

```
function selected() {
var i = 0;
$("#names").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
        i++;
        $("#checked").text("Sum  Checked: " + i);
    }

})
};
$("#checked").text("Sum Checked: ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
$('#names input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $("#checked").text($('#names input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);

});
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="names">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 1</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 2</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 3</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 4</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 5</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" class="check">Name 6</label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
Sum Checked: <span id="checked">0</span>
```

Comment: This does the trick. Although, if I were to place it in a named function, and use it in the document.ready, will it just update itself everytime?

Comment: sure.. why not.. actually `$(function(){` at start is `document.ready` only